# Inserting HTML into iframe doesn't grab image from the server in Firefox, but it does in Chrome. Why would this be?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, mustache

I have a page that is used for uploading a file to be used as a logo inside an iframe, which is located on the same page. After uploading (via POST to /api/defaults/logo), the iframe should update with the new logo. This works in Chrome and Safari, but not in FF.

The code in question:

```
this.getMessagePreviewArea().html(renderedHtml);

getMessagePreviewArea: function() {
    // SVG render bug fix: begin
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177190/svg-dynamically-added-to-iframe-does-not-render-correctly
    this.$('iframe')[0].contentDocument.open();
    this.$('iframe')[0].contentDocument.close();
    // SVG render bug fix: end
    return $(this.$('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.body);
}
```

renderedHtml is pretty basic HTML, generated by Mustache, but it contains:

```
<img class='logo-img' src='/api/defaults/logo'>
```

That api endpoint is what's not being called. If I refresh the page, it hits the server and grabs the new image fine, but it should be able to do that as soon as the HTML is inserted into the iframe, right?

Sorry if the syntax seems off, it's written with Backbone.js.

Answer (score 0):

cache? Probably you should try to add timestamp to src like: '/api/defaults/logo?42346546745'

Comment: Should've mentioned I did try using a time stamp as a cachebuster, but it didn't seem to help.